# Regex:How to take text & some special characters between the Xml tags using Regex on vb.net or C#.net

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I want to take the text and some special characters between the xml tags..
My input file contains:

```
<line>public static void main(String[] args)</line>
<line>{</line>
<line>   <>double <inline>result</inline> = Math.pow(2, 3);</line>
<line>   . . .</line>
<line>    </line> 'white space also comes
<line>}</line>
```

now i want the Regex to take text and the special characters between the tags `<line>,<inline>..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing it as an XML will fail because of the <> before "double". I'd not use Regex for this either, but simple String.Replace will perform better or StringBuilder would be even better.
This works fine for me:

```
string test = @"<line>public static void main(String[] args)</line> 
    <line>{</line> 
    <line>   <>double <inline>result</inline> = Math.pow(2, 3);</line> 
    <line>   . . .</line> 
    <line>    </line> 'white space also comes 
    <line>}</line>
    ";

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(test);
new List<String>() { "<line>", "<inline>", "</line>", "</inline>" }.ForEach(token => str.Replace(token, String.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
```

UPDATE:

with this it should work in .net 2.0 too:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(test);
List<String> tokens = new List<String>();
tokens.Add("<line>");
tokens.Add("<inline>");
tokens.Add("</line>");
tokens.Add("</inline>");

foreach(String token in tokens)
{
    str.Replace(token, String.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to parse XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<lines>
<line>public static void main(String[] args)</line>
<line>{</line>
<line>   &lt;&gt;double <inline>result</inline> = Math.pow(2, 3);</line>
<line>   . . .</line>
<line>    </line> &apos;white space also comes
<line>}</line>
</lines>", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

string result = doc.Root.Value;

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

*Output:*

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   <>double result = Math.pow(2, 3);
   . . .
     'white space also comes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur rply.. But i am using .net version 2.0.